# Github: what is the most efficient way to push many projects up to Github?

Tags: git, github, project

I'm new to Github and have 30 separate react projects I'd like to push up to my Github, in order to showcase as part of my portfolio. I would ideally like to create one sort of 'folder' where all the 30 projects sit, but as far as I know it doesn't seem possible. So I guess I have to push each one up separately, and create a git ignore for each and every project. Is there a more efficient way to do this, or do I have to set some time aside to go through every single project separately?

Comment: GitHub pages. HTML. Links. Done.

Comment: You could upload the entire folder containing all your projects and have a web page link to each of the subfolders seperately whilst keeping them all contained in one repository. This wouldnt be ideal for continuing work on them though so dont do this if you want to use github for its intended purpose on these projects

Comment: and then create one gitignore in the parent folder or would i have to create 30 gitignores in the 30 subfolders?